# Any method to make TiffBitmapEncoder faster?

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I have a method that converts raw image to tif. the codec for raw image is installed:

```
private void SaveTiff(string filename, string output)
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder bmpDec = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(filename), System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.None);

        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource srs = bmpDec.Frames[0];

        if (Path.GetExtension(output).Equals(".tif", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create))
            {
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Compression = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffCompressOption.None;
                encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(srs));
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }   
}
```

It works fine. However, the image size is 4928x3264 with 48bppRGB. It takes more than 20 seconds to convert on an average PC (16GB, 4 core, 3.1GHZ). Is there a way to make it faster? The colordepth and dpi can be changed, but the tif has to be uncompressed. I tried to change colordepth, dpi, and even size, it still takes about similar time. my guess, it is because it has to decode the raw image first, which takes time because of the codec. Is this correct? Any other suggestions?

When we use BitmapImage, we could use DecodePixelWidth to save memory, probably time, is there a siilar method/property for BitmapSource (which is what I use)?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried profiling that code? That will usually let you know what your hotspots are

Comment: I did not profile it, but based on debug, "encoder.Save(stream);" takes time. If you use the same code with a tif image directly, it takes no time.

Comment: instead of saving to a `FileStream` try saving to a `MemoryStream` instead and see if that makes a difference. Underneath this code is Windows Imaging Component which is usually quite fast. I would still highly suggest using a profiler, VS2010 Premium and up have one built in that would work.